# npm update check failed version 5.6.0

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to use npm but it isn't working for me. It gives me an error like:

[image]

Is there anyone who can tell me what I have to do? 
I'm using version 5.6.0.

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept her

Answer (score 0):

npm version should get updated.

```
npm i -g npm
```