# i am unable to install NPM packages in my react native project

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

Simultaneously I am seeing `npm update check failed` message on the screen. Are these both related? please help me to go in detail.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeNjx.png)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48742630/npm-update-check-failed-version-5-6-0

Answer (score 0):

Can you try deleting your Node modules folder and then try? also, you can try reinstalling the npm ([How to Reinstall Broken npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748307/how-to-reinstall-broken-npm))

Comment: i tried by deleting node modules folder and running the npm start command(no result).

While trying  Reinstalling broken npm, it is showing an error after running npm i -g npm command. error states that "remove the exsisting file and try again" though i deleted the npm folder and downloaded and updated as you said.